# Find and push element in a vector in the same method

Tags: vector, rust, borrow-checker

I've the feeling that my implementation is too cumbersome and I guess there is a better way to implement this simple thing.

I have a `Grid` struct representing a game board, I have a method to add a cell into grid, this method (`add_cell`) checks if a cell already exists in the grid before to add it.

```
struct Cell {
    // A simplified version with only one coordinate
    position: i8,
}

struct Grid {
    // List of cells in the grid
    cells: Vec<Rc<Cell>>,
}

impl Grid {
    // Add a cell in to the grid
    pub fn add_cell(&mut self, cell: Cell) {
        let is_not_yet_in;
        {
            if self.cells.iter().find(|&c| c.position == cell.position).is_some() {
                is_not_yet_in = false;
            } else {
                is_not_yet_in = true;
            }
        }
        if is_not_yet_in {
            self.cells.push(Rc::new(cell).clone());
        }
    }
}
```

I put the *fake* scope, after `is_not_yet_in` declaration, in order to avoid compiling error on mutable/immutable borrowing of `self.cells`. Anyway I think this trick can be avoid using a different approach.

Comment: Removing the scope after the declaration [does not](http://is.gd/kI9O3U) have any errors... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read over and commit to memory the methods of the [`Iterator` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). Specifically, you want [`any`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any) here. I also flipped the polarity on your variable name to match.

```
pub fn add_cell(&mut self, cell: Cell) {
    let is_present = self.cells.iter().any(|c| c.position == cell.position);
    if !is_present {
        self.cells.push(Rc::new(cell).clone());
    }
}
```

Additionally, `Rc::new(cell).clone()` doesn't make any sense — you might as well shorten it to `Rc::new(cell)`.

Comment: Good! Thank you. So I guess this behaviour is due to how the iterators work (lazy evaluation), right? Since of that if I write `let ... = self.cells.iter().find(...).is_some()` it also works.